# Can't acces web admin using internal IP address and port

Tags: geoserver, proxy, administration

Version: Geoserver 2.22.2

I have geoserver running behind an haproxy.
Geoserver is configured with a "Proxy Base URL" in the "Global" Settings.
The web admin interface is restricted for internal IP in haproxy.
Using the internal IP and port I can log in successfully, but it immediately redirects me to the base proxy url, which is restricted by the haproxy.

This was working ok in an older version of Geoserver. Nothing has been changed.

For completeness. Im successfully logging in via http://local_ip_address:port/geosever/web, but the login page redirects me to https://www.external.com/geoserver/web.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of the proxy url setting is to redirect all requests to the proxy location.

If however you want or need to access the Web GUI on the original address and port then you can change the [`WebUI Mode` setting](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html#webui-mode) on the Global settings page from `redirect` to `do not redirect`.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I only want the proxy for external consumption, not for administration. That was the way it worked in previous versions. The problem for me arose when I upgraded to latest version.

Comment: I have the same issue, i.e. I use proxyBaseUrl setting in global.xml, however I don't want redirection when I log onto the geoserver web UI. The DO_NOT_REDIRECT setting does not change this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, if you need to set a proxyBaseUrl to appear in the Geoserver GetCapabilities responses, but you don't want the web UI to redirect to the proxy url at log on, the proxyBaseUrl shall be set in the workspace settings (https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/data/webadmin/workspaces.html#workspace-settings) not in the global settings (https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html).